# Wizard of Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin for a new project: Next button is disabled

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I read this [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html) to install the KMM plugin on Android Studio.
On the first page: I set the main config of the project,
then I wanted to set go to the second page to set the name of the application (android, ios, shared modules) but the next button is disabled!
and if I click on the finish button, the project will be created but without anything in there!

[image: kmm-wizard]

*I think the issue is because of my OS (Windows 10) but it mustn't be a barrier to creating the project.*

Answer (score 2):

See this [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41559#focus=Comments-27-4371632.0-0):

> Unfortunately, the functionality is restricted in this way by default in Android Studio 4.0.1 (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/setup.html). Please use at least 4.1 RC 1 instead.